# angularjs bindToController can't invoke method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive set up like this:

```
angular.module('widget.directives').directive('applePay', applePay);

function applePay() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'ApplePayController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        scope: {
            onCheckComplete: '&applePay'
        },
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/apple-pay/apple-pay.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.find('button').bind('click', controller.checkout);
        }
    };
};
```

And it's controller looks like this:

```
angular.module('widget.directives').controller('ApplePayController', applePayController);

applePayController.$inject = ['applePayService'];

function applePayController(applePayService) {
    var self = this;

    // Method binding
    self.checkout = checkout;

    init();

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function init() {
        applePayService.checkAvailability(setAvailability);
    };

    function setAvailability(available) {
        self.available = available === true;
        console.log(self);
        self.onCheckComplete({ available: self.available });
    };

    function checkout(e) {
        applePayService.checkout(e, onComplete, onError);
    };

    function onComplete(result, completion) {
        console.log(result, completion);
    };

    function onError(error) {
        self.error = error;
    };
};
```

My html for this is like this:

```
<div apple-pay="controller.applePayAvailable(available)"></div>
```

When the directive loads I get an error:

> TypeError: self.onCheckComplete is not a function

Does anyone know why?
I have a similar directive and that works fine.

Comment: In the function `setAvailability` you call this function `self.onCheckComplete({ available: self.available });` but it doesn't seem defined inside the controller

Comment: Nah, I figured it out actually. It's becuase the init is invoked in the controller **before** the scope has been bound to the controller. I had to add the init method to the link method

Comment: That's not the recommended approach in 1.6.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the **Controller** has an init method which is invoked when the controller is instantiated. The problem with that is that the scope hasn't been bound yet. So I had to change the controller to this:

```
angular.module('widget.directives').controller('ApplePayController', applePayController);

applePayController.$inject = ['applePayService'];

function applePayController(applePayService) {
    var self = this;

    // Method binding
    self.init = init;
    self.checkout = checkout;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function init() {
        applePayService.checkAvailability(setAvailability);
    };

    function setAvailability(available) {
        self.available = available === true;
        console.log(self);
        self.onCheckComplete({ available: self.available });
    };

    function checkout(e) {
        applePayService.checkout(e, onComplete, onError);
    };

    function onComplete(result, completion) {
        console.log(result, completion);
    };

    function onError(error) {
        self.error = error;
    };
};
```

and then add the init method to the link function on the directive.

```
angular.module('widget.directives').directive('applePay', applePay);

function applePay() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/apple-pay/apple-pay.html',
        controller: 'ApplePayController',
        controllerAs: 'controller',
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            onCheckComplete: '&applePay'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.find('button').bind('click', controller.checkout);
            controller.init();
        }
    };
};
```

The only difference between from above is adding the init method as a public method on the controller and then calling `controller.init()` from the directive. That ensures the scope is bound before the initiation.

Comment: This seems odd. What version of angularJS are you using?

Comment: 1.6.4 but I don't think it's odd, it is the way the digest cycle works. Controllers are instantiated before directives so the scope won't be available at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I found this odd because I have some 1.5x code doing this exact same thing without issues. After learning you are on 1.6x, I did some digging around to understand what was going on. The change that is impacting things here is for a property called `preAssignBindingsEnabled`. This breaking change was documented in this [gitHub post](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bcd0d4d896d0dfdd988ff4f849c1d40366125858). It's also part of the migration [document here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)

In the migration doc there is a great code snippet that I think you'll find helpful for your situation allowing you to keep your `link()` function all about DOM manipulation and not worrying about calling into the controller. Under the Core:Services --> $compile section of the migration doc, it shows a directive with a controller declaration using the 1.5x `$onInit()` hook syntax to ensure bindings are present before the controller initializes.

I adapted this to your scenario:

```
function applePayController(applePayService) {
  var self = this;

  // Method binding
  self.checkout = checkout;

  //**Hook below to ensure bindings are set when preAssignBindingsEnabled is 
  //false (default setting with 1.6x**)

  self.$onInit = init;

  //init();

  function init() {
    applePayService.checkAvailability(setAvailability);
  };

  .
  .
  .
 };
```

Once bindings are all set, the controller's $onInit will automagically be called by Angular, and the function executed as normal. Hope this offers some additional options!